# Can a spring app hosted on app engine communicate with couchbase on compute engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-compute-engine, couchbase

Planning on deploying a spring boot application on google compute engine. Couchbase is located on a google compute engine instance. Will the app be able to communicate with the database?

I'm no deployment expert so bear with me, if you have any other suggestions for hosting such an application (keeping in mind performance), please do tell.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it should work. I've assisted others who have deployed to GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine).  The only tough parts are giving consistent hostnames/IPs to the clients and the servers, as Couchbase will retrieve the topology from the cluster.  Thus the cluster needs to know resolvable hostnames or you'll need to implement split horizon name resolution, etc.  You'll find other posts over on forums.couchbase.com covering similar tech.